# Vim: How to substitute in visual block or in range of lines with decrementing certain number

Tags: vim

Let say I have this input:

```
{3:3} abc  
{3:4} def hjkl
```

Ouput should be:

```
{3:2} abc  
{3:3} def hjkl
```

so decrementing number at beginning of line after ':' before '}'.
Please note that this should work only for selected visual block, not for entire buffer/file (or in range of lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (even shorter) solution:

```
:exe "'<,'>norm 0f:\<C-X>"
```

But if you don't mind using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to get `^X`, you could use the following code:

```
:'<,'>norm 0f:^X
```

where `^X` (from [`:help CTRL-X`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#CTRL-X)):

> Subtracts from the number or alphabetic character at or after the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In visual block one possible solution:

```
:`<,`>s/:\(\d\+\)}/\=":".(submatch(1) -1)."}"/g
```

Comment: Please note: even though you're using a visual block your command will actually be run on the entire line (see [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6898/6698) and [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7388/6698) questions). Incidentally, it could be shorten to `:'<,'>s/:\zs\d\+\ze}/\=submatch(0)-1/g`

Comment: @JairLopez: `:'<,'>s/\%V:\zs\d\+\ze}\%V/\=submatch(0)-1/g` will ensure the match is fully inside visual block (and leave out parts of the line not covered by the visual block).